# Overlapping UIImageViews on screen: select the right view

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview

I am creating an iPhone app in which the user taps structures on an image of an MRI scan to select regions of interest and calculate a score. Each screen contains a UIView with multiple UIImage views. Each UIImageView that is touched by the user is "highlighted". However, on one of the screens the structures of interest are so close together that the frame rectangles of the UIImageView overlap (3 of them). Now, tapping in some areas highlights the wrong image. Rearranging views does not help (moving to front or back) doesn't help, there is a large area of overlap. I included a screen shot of the Storyboard and corresponding code of the view controller. Can anybody think of a solution??
[image]
override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set, with event: UIEvent?)
{

```
    let touch = touches.first!
    
    switch touch.view {
        
    case PO_PV_R:
        if PO_PV_R.isHighlighted == false
        {
            PO_PV_R.isHighlighted = true
            loesScore.parieto_occipital_R_perivent = 0.5
        }
        else
        {
            PO_PV_R.isHighlighted = false
            loesScore.parieto_occipital_R_perivent = 0.0
        }
    
    case PO_C_R:
        if PO_C_R.isHighlighted == false
        {
            PO_C_R.isHighlighted = true
            loesScore.parieto_occipital_R_central = 0.5
        }
        else
        {
            PO_C_R.isHighlighted = false
            loesScore.parieto_occipital_R_central = 0.0
        }
        
    case PO_SC_R:
        if PO_SC_R.isHighlighted == false
        {
            PO_SC_R.isHighlighted = true
            loesScore.parieto_occipital_R_subcortical = 0.5
        }
        else
        {
            PO_SC_R.isHighlighted = false
            loesScore.parieto_occipital_R_subcortical = 0.0
        }
        
    default:
        print("default")
        
    }
    
    let score = loesData.shared.totalLoesScore()
    scoreLabel.text = String(format:"%.1f", score)
    
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to detect touches **inside the red paths**? If so, do you already have those paths defined to draw the outlines? Or... do you have duplicate images, one with and one without the red path?

Comment: Yes, exactly: I want to detect the touches inside the red paths only. I do not have those paths defined; I used images I drew in Photoshop that I export as PNG and assign to the UIImageView.

Comment: If you do not have pre-defined paths, things will be a little tricky. Can you post the 4 images for this example (so we can see what you are working with)?